# How can I en- and decompress a bootable image?

Tags: windows, programming, assembly, mingw

I have a bootable kernel image, that I had created with MinGW Toolchain's that available for Microsoft Windows 11.
The Project is in size tiny, but I would know: "How can I shrink the image, if it grow to pass it on a Floppy Disk."

Thanks for Ideas.

Edit:
You can found a Example OS for this request at my git account: [**paule32**](https://github.com/paule32/JustFunOS_win32/releases/tag/Release)

Comment: You have 5 questions in 1 question post. That's too many. Also, your title seems to have very little to do with most of these questions. Please focus on **one** question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to zip the image, add it to the End of a Stub-File.
The Stub-File contain de-zip Code, and the Stub loads then the de-packed Image from Memory.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, and thanks for your contribution - both the question and the answer. However I think the answer would benefit if you [edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736534/edit) and expanded it. As it is now, for example I have no clue what to do without diving into huge amounts of web searching. A sort of step-by-step, with some links to resources for further info would be good.